# STM32H750B-DK ADC sample rate calculation

Tags: stm32, adc, timer, dma

I am making an oscilloscope. I am using ADC with configuration like this:

[image]

[image]

And I am triggering my ADC with 1 ms (at least I think it is (was always confused on how to calculate its tick, so I just set PSC to 0 to make it easier for myself)) TIM6 which is configured as:

[image]

Then I send my samples over UART (115200 bps 8N1) to PC (I know UART is my bottleneck but I need sample rate before UART) like this:

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD1_GPIO_Port, LD1_Pin);

    VRefInt = __HAL_ADC_CALC_VREFANALOG_VOLTAGE(DMABuf[0], //Reference voltage
                      hadc3.Init.Resolution);
    ADC_INP0    = __HAL_ADC_CALC_DATA_TO_VOLTAGE(VRefInt, DMABuf[1], //PC2_C -> A5
                      hadc3.Init.Resolution);
    ADC_INP1    = __HAL_ADC_CALC_DATA_TO_VOLTAGE(VRefInt, DMABuf[2], //PC3_C -> A6
                      hadc3.Init.Resolution);
    //Send over UART
    byteTXFunc(VRefInt & 0x00FF);
    byteTXFunc((VRefInt & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    byteTXFunc(ADC_INP0 & 0x00FF);
    byteTXFunc((ADC_INP0 & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    byteTXFunc(ADC_INP1 & 0x00FF);
    byteTXFunc((ADC_INP1 & 0xFF00) >> 8);
}
```

I am using 240 MHz CPU Clock and my clock configuration looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now everything works fine but the highest signal I can see is 955 Hz (which means my sample rate is probably 1.91 kHz (955*2=1910 Hz).

Now I cannot figure out where this limitation comes from, I am using 240 MHz CPU clock and I am constantly triggering ADC with 1 ms (I just want to know why is there this limitation, maybe if I use high speed timer, I could increase this, but that's not important right now), I also use DMA to get samples out of ADC so CPU is not involved).

I did figure out that if I increase CPU frequency (it was 72 MHz before and the highest signal I could see was even lower) that my sample rate also increases so sample rate is somehow related to CPU frequency.

So why is my sample rate that low (I would expect it at least like 1Mhz or something (if I use 240 MHz CPU clock).

Comment: You sample limit is (currently) entirely dependent on your UART baud rate. 115200 translates into 11520 bytes/sec. You're sending 6 bytes/sample, so 11520/6 == 1920 samples/sec.

Comment: oh that totaly makes sense, at first I thought my UART sample rate is 11.52khz because I thought 1 bit is 1 cycle per second)

Where did you figure out that I am sending 6bytes/sample? (Maybe I don't see something obvious here :) )

Also, how do I calculate ADC sample rate (lets say, I want to replace UART with USB or draw to screen direcly)

Comment: In this sort of application, you're going to want to collect the data from the ADC as fast as possible and buffer it in the MCU's memory. Then you can send the buffer out over the UART for as long as it takes. Of course, this means that you can't continuously stream data.

Comment: Yea I know, I just wanted to make PoC first

But my sample rate is 1910 (maximum received frequency was 955Hz) not 1920 (do u have any idea where could 10 samples be lost?)

Comment: In your code you call `byteTXFunc` 6 times - so you're sending 6 bytes every time you take a sample.

Comment: OK that makes sense now, the onlything still confusing to me is whats my sample rate before UART. At first I guess if I trigger ADC with 1ms then its 1khz right? (does ADC internal clock and sample rate even matter if I trigger it with a TIM6 or will my sample rate always be 1khz in this case?)

Comment: As long as you've configured the ADC internal clock and internal timing parameters such that it's able to sample at least as fast as your timer triggers it, then for many applications the exact timing doesn't matter.

Comment: I see so if I understand you corecly, My ADC Internal clock is 50Mhz (thats what clock configuration is showing (where it says To ADC 50Mhz)

and my timer triggers with 3Mhz (according to the configuration picture I provided), everything will be fine

So as long as my timer triggers adc with frequency thats lower then ADC Internal clock everything will be fine. What if I trigger with bigger frequency then ADC Internal clock?